# Conic section's vector equation???

Tags: geometry, vectors, conic-sections, 3d

Hello I have curiosity on how will be the vector equation of conic section's on 3d space. For example I have tried with $\vec x = \vec a *t^2+\vec b *t + \vec c$ for parabola but not shure how probe this. Thanks and please excuse my English.

Comment: You want curves, not a [quadric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric)? Do you want those curves to lie in a place in 3d? If not, how exactly do you want to generalize the concept of a conic section?

Comment: Yes a curve in 3d space. Thanks.

Comment: “Place” should have been “plane” in my previous comment: are you talking about planar curves, or non-planar ones?

Comment: I'm sorry. Planar curves in arbitrary planes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}$Here is one approach, very similar to yours (with conditions on the vectors $\Vec{a}$ and $\Vec{b}$ to ensure the resulting curve is congruent to a known plane conic):

Suppose $(x(t), y(t)$ is a parametrization of some conic in the Cartesian plane $\Reals^{2}$.

If $\Vec{x}_{0}$ is a point of $\Reals^{n}$, and if $\Basis_{1}$, $\Basis_{2}$ are an orthonormal pair in $\Reals^{n}$, then
$$
\Vec{x}(t) = \Vec{x}_{0} + x(t) \Basis_{1} + y(t) \Basis_{2}
$$
parametrizes a conic in the plane through $\Vec{x}_{0}$ and spanned by $\Basis_{1}$, $\Basis_{2}$.

Comment: Thanks this is really cool, Can you tell me how can i made my own demo?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know in detail how to create a parametric curve to trace a conic in a particular plane? (The short answer is: Each of $\Vec{x}_0$, $\Basis_1$, $\Basis_2$ is an ordered triple of real numbers, so the given formula for $\Vec{x}(t)$ can be expanded to an ordered triple of functions of $t$.)